# Remove from git tracking files according to new gitignore

Tags: git

I deploy a Rails app on VPS. I use my git repo on bitbucket to sync files on my work and home computers so it is trashed with unnecessary in production binary files.

I modified .gitignore file so it excludes some paths in my app from being tracked. But when I push my changes to remote repo (from there capistrano takes production version) it keeps to track .gitignored files and git clone copy all stuff with garbage.

How to replace on remote repo master branch with my new cleaned local master(which I created by re-init git)? Or how to make remote repo remove from tracking tree .gitignored files?
thank you very-very

Comment: Do I take it you want to "untrack" some files? edit: see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your .gitignore file is NOT enough if some files, which .gitignore matches, are tracked by the index.

As they are tracked by the index, they are in the checked out tree, therefore in the commits etc.

If you want to "untrack" those files, your best option is to use a dedicated form of `git rm` for this purpose:

```
# Rinse, repeat for each file, or use several paths/globs/etc
git rm --cached path/to/unwanted/file
```

Then commit the result. The `--cached` option means to remove this file *from the index only*, and not the working tree.

Comment: I'm sorry for being not clear: my english is still somewhat ambiguous. I know how to remove files from the local index, but my capistrano deploying script clones production version of my app from bitbucket-repo, which is contaminated with lot of jpegs. So I need to remove unnecessary files from the remoted index

Comment: Well, yes, so what? This is the same. Just push the modified index to the remote.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand your question, but if you want to remove all the files that match the contents of your .gitignore you can:

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-standard
```

Which shows you the files, and if you actually want to delete them:

```
git rm $(git ls-files -i --exclude-standard)
```

Comment: thanks, 'git rm $(git ls-files -i --exclude-standard)' doesn't work on windows, any alternative?

Comment: Ok, what I did 
`git ls-files -i --exclude-standard >  ../gitignoreremovers.log`
and then cleaned using 
`xargs git rm < ../gitignoreremovers.log`